# addEventListener and angularjs promise : wrap it up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angular-promise

I am trying to wrap my head around on drawing the line between event listeners/handlers and the resolution of a promise with angularjs.

I'm using PreloadJS in an angularjs service dealing with audio.
That service is used as a dependency for another service which needs to be able to perform some actions once the files have been preloaded (hence the use of a promise).

But I have no clue left on how to wrap it up all together...

So, classical bit of code :

```
// Event handlers
audio.queue.addEventListener('fileload', function(event) {
  console.log('charging file', event);
  // do some things while loading (.notify)
});

audio.queue.addEventListener('complete', function(event) {
  console.log('file loaded', event);
  // do some things once it's loaded (.resolve)
});

audio.queue.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  console.log('error while charging file', event);
  // do some things in case of error (.reject)
});

// Preload a file
audio.queue.loadFile({id: 'test', src: 'test.mp3'});
```

What could I do?
A. `$q.all` on an array of promises fed by the 3 callbacks?
B. I have no B...

Any help or leads will be appreciated

## EDIT:

In response to [C14L answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112585/1156542).  Let's admit we have:

```
var file1 = 'test.mp3' //file exists
var file2 = 'azepsl.mp3' //file doesnt exist
var file3 = 'test2.mp3' //file exists
```

with [C14L code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112585/1156542) I got 3 promises rejected because of the 1 file that doesn't exist.
If I use plain old eventHandler as shown above, I got 2 success events and 1 failure (which is pretty normal).

What could be the cause of this issue?
Could it be because of several `eventListeners` added to `audio.queue`?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `fileload` fires during file download, so not needed if you want to handle the file *after* download. You only need `complete` and `error`. You could wrap that in a promise

```
function download_me_stuff(){
  audio.queue.loadFile({id: 'test', src: 'test.mp3'});

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    audio.queue.addEventListener('complete', function(event) {
      console.log('file loaded', event);
      resolve(event);
    });
    audio.queue.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
      console.log('error while charging file', event);
      reject(event);
    });
  }
}
```

Now its thenable

```
download_me_stuff().then(
    function do_me_things (event) {
      // ...
    },
    function handle_me_error (event) { 
      // ...
    }
);
```

Was that what you asked for? I may have misunderstood.

---

**Edit:**

I had a look at the [fileload spec](http://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html#event_fileload) and it looks like this event is fired *every time* one individual file from the queue finished loading successfully.

```
audio.queue.addEventListener('fileload', function(event) {
  console.log('one more file loaded', event);
});
```

While the `complete` event is fired once *all* files are loaded successfully. In your example, you were only loading one file, but lets use 3 files. They are all added to the file queue

```
audio.queue.loadFile({id: 'test1', src: 'test1.jpg'});
audio.queue.loadFile({id: 'test2', src: 'test2.jpg'});
audio.queue.loadFile({id: 'test3', src: 'test3.jpg'});
```

You probably want to react every time a *single file* has loaded and do stuff with that one file. While you could wrap that into individual promises, it would just complicate stuff. Better to simply define the callback

```
audio.queue.addEventListener('fileload', oneSingleFileLoaded);

function oneSingleFileLoaded(event) {
  var id = event.item.id; // 'id' of this item from loadFile() above
  var type = event.item.type;

  if (type == createjs.LoadQueue.IMAGE) {
    document.getElementById('#'+id).appendChild(event.result);
  }
}
```

The other two events are just for convenience, to let you know if the *entire queue* was loaded successfully or not. Probably not that important in most cases

```
audio.queue.addEventListener('complete', function(event) {
  alert('Wohooo, everything downloaded successfully!')
});

audio.queue.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  alert("Well, that didn't work. Hit [F5] and try again!");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the promise creation syntax I didn't know. But unfortunately, it doesn't totally fix the issue as explained in my edit.